# Compare datetime elements in a list c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-4.0, compare

I have list of `datetime` values and I am trying to compare each item against all items.

```
var dateList = new List<DateTime>();
```

Basically I want to check all the items are equal or not.

Think I can use [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx), but I am not sure how to go through each element and compare.

Comment: what kind of result do you expect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Basically I want to check all the items are equal or not.

No need for `DateTime.Compare`. Just check

```
dateList.Distinct().Count();
```

If it is equal to 1 then they are equal but if it is more than 1 then No, they are not equal.

Comment: @log nice fix but what if the author really meant 0? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var notAllEqual = dateList.Any(x => x != dateList.First())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool b = dateList.Skip(1).All(x=>x.Equals(dateList[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-Linq approach:

```
    bool AreAllDatesEqual(List<DateTime> dateList)
    {
        var first = dateList[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < dateList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (first != dateList[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: this compares just one item with all. OP wants each item with all.

Comment: @Reniuz - However, the end result is the same! Check it out yourself :-)

Comment: +1 This is basically the same as [L.B's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12052849/284240) without Linq.